# WCF service VS JSon in Silverlight view

Tags: json, silverlight-3.0, wcf

I have developed one view in Silverlight and currently using WCF services to take data (around 10 MB) from Server to Silverlight view. Even though there is no processing at server side and server is taking less than 1 sec from request recieve to response return but I am getting response in Silverlight after 50 sec. I have deployed WCF service in IIS and enabled HTTP compression which improve response time from 50 sec to 30 sec but still it is not acceptable.

Now I am thinking to move from WCF to JSON if it improve response time. Will it help me to improve response of the application?

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer in its present state.

It depends on where the bottleneck in the service is. IIS compression will use more CPU resources, but less bandwidth, and given this improved the response time, It would seem like bandwidth is the issue.

Moving to JSON may reduce bandwidth another 5-10%.

but this is not a WCF vs JSON question, as you can use JSON from WCF (defining a custom serializer)

If your service was limited by CPU eliminating WCF may have worked, but you would need to manually do considerably more work, And may not do it as efficiently as WCF anyway.

As with all performance issues, profiling is your friend.